# Error con 86,178 Inserts en SQLServer BD Local

Tags: sql-server, script, insert

Me encuentro realizando 86,178 inserts en una base de datos local, pero cuando corro la ejecución por `SQLCMD` me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Msg 701, Level 17, State 123, Server 3534-LAP0099\PSEJECUCION, Line -617
There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
```

El comando que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost\PSEjecucion -E -i ActualizarMIS1.sql -a 32767 -o LogSQLMIS.txt
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con una solución?

Cabe mencionar que los inserts no tienen error de sintaxis, esto lo sé por que lo he ejecutado por partes, disminuyendo la cantidad de inserts por script.

Ojala me puedan dar una ayudita,

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema con la cantidad de recursos que usa tu consulta, lo que indica el error es que no tienes suficiente memoria RAM para procesar la misma, es decir sqlserver necesita 500mb y tienes 450mb por ejemplo... De allí que si dividis la consulta en parte si lo puedas lograr.

Puedes intentar optimizar la consulta, otra cosa que puedes hacer (si crees que tu computadora tiene memoria suficiente) es configurar el sqlserver para que utilice más de la misma cuando trabaje. Para ello debes:

- Abrir el management studio
- En el explorador de objetos pulsar con el botón derecho del mouse en **(local) (SQL Server xx.xx.xxx)**.
- Selecciona propiedades y luego seleccionar memoria
- Debajo de **memoria máxima del servidor**, indica la memoria que quieres que utilice el servidor

[image: Propiedades del servidor]